# How can I re-authenticate a Server when a NETLOGON (5719) error occured, when the machine lost connection to the DC and the connection returned?

Tags: authentication, netlogon

Greetings Superior minds. I hope you can spare some valuebale time to assist me with this problem for I have limmited knowledge on Servers and Domain Controllers.

**Background:**
I have SCADA software that runs on a couple of servers and then client software that reads the information from these servers. All of which is joined to a local domain. On ocasions one or two of the servers data doesn't get read from the servers. When I restart the server everything comes back up and works again. The SCADA software uses a common domain user to communicate with each other. The servers are running Windows 2008 R2.

**Observations:**
In my software log files it seems like the server lost authentication with the domain controller.
I am getting this error (see error below) in my Windows Event logger about the same time I experience problems with my software.

```
This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain SGLENG due to the following:
There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
This may lead to authentication problems. Make sure that this computer is connected to the network.
If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator.

ADDITIONAL INFO
If this computer is a domain controller for the specified domain, it sets up the secure
session to the primary domain controller emulator in the specified domain. Otherwise, this
 computer sets up the secure session to any domain controller in the specified domain.
```

**My Question:**
How can I re-authenticate the server with a script without restarting the server?

I know I can detect the event and then run a scheduled task which in turn can trigger a script, but I did not find any powershell commands or any other scripting commands to authenticate the user on the server to the domain controller.

If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated. I can do the resulting script in any of: Power-shell or VBScript or JScript or Python 3.x or C or C++.

The server is probably doing this because of intermittent network connectivity at times, but I don't have control over the network and i don't see the networking department sorting out his problem anytime soon.

Thank You.